# Error converting java.lang.String to JSONObject

Tags: android

I access a web service from the andriod emulator and am able to but the output i get is something like this as shown [below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h91dv.png) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>  <ArrayOfQuestionnaire xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">  <Questionnaire>   <QuestionnaireId>0</QuestionnaireId>   <QuestionnaireName>Microsoft 0</QuestionnaireName>    </Questionnaire>  <Questionnaire>   <QuestionnaireId>1</QuestionnaireId>   <QuestionnaireName>Microsoft 1</QuestionnaireName>    </Questionnaire>  <Questionnaire>   <QuestionnaireId>2</QuestionnaireId>   <QuestionnaireName>Microsoft 2</QuestionnaireName>    </Questionnaire>  <Questionnaire>   <QuestionnaireId>3</QuestionnaireId>   <QuestionnaireName>Microsoft 3</QuestionnaireName>    </Questionnaire>  <Questionnaire>   <QuestionnaireId>4</QuestionnaireId>   <QuestionnaireName>Microsoft 4</QuestionnaireName>    </Questionnaire>  <Questionnaire>   <QuestionnaireId>5</QuestionnaireId>   <QuestionnaireName>Microsoft 5</QuestionnaireName>    </Questionnaire>  <Questionnaire>   <QuestionnaireId>6</QuestionnaireId>   <QuestionnaireName>Microsoft 6</QuestionnaireName>    </Questionnaire>  <Questionnaire>   <QuestionnaireId>7</QuestionnaireId>   <QuestionnaireName>Microsoft 7</QuestionnaireName>    </Questionnaire>  <Questionnaire>   <QuestionnaireId>8</QuestionnaireId>   <QuestionnaireName>Microsoft 8</QuestionnaireName>    </Questionnaire>  <Questionnaire>   <QuestionnaireId>9</QuestionnaireId>   <QuestionnaireName>Microsoft 9</QuestionnaireName>    </Questionnaire> </ArrayOfQuestionnaire>
```

I want to be able to parse data to the JSON format . Isnt it suppose to send data in the JSON format ?

When i try to access with the code

> JSONObject JResponse = new
>   JSONObject(content);    String
>   sMessage =
>   JResponse.getString("QuestionnaireName");
>      int success =
>   JResponse.getInt("QuestionnaireId");

Anyways i get the error saying

```
   Value <?xml of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject ????
```

Any idea on how to go about this ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is XML not JSON. There is no point converting XML to JSON on the client and then parse JSON. You need to use Java's XML parser or simply return JSON from the server.

Comment: Hi Aliostad , Thank you for your reply . How do i return my data in the JSON format ? I tried adding the attribute [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat=ResponseFormat.Json)] but this just doesnt work . I mean it returns in the XML format . Am i missing on somthing ?

Comment: That is a separate question that has nothing to do with Android. Please create another question and tag it appropriately and if it is in ASP.NET, post the link here and I will try to answer.